# How do I get a power in Warframe?

Tags: warframe

I went through the Tutorial and completed a mission, but I can't seem to figure out what I need to do, or where I assign powers.

I am playing the PS4 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** The original of this was correct when it was written; MMOs change as time goes on an it's no longer even remotely accurate.

Your Warframe will automatically unlock abilities as it levels up.

The first ability is always available; the second, third and fourth ability unlock at levels 3, 5 and 10.

(Data taken from [here](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Warframes) under the 'abilities' tab.)